# I think my html file doesn't see another script file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this problem .I have two file one (`soap.html`) and other is (`soap.js`)

In the html file , I'm using a function which is `edarah_Authenticate` , and this function is exist in the `soap.js` , but this is the error :

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: edarah_Authenticate is not defined "

How can I make the html file see the function in the `soap.js` file

here is the HTML:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="soap.js"> </script>

 <input type="text" name="username" 
 id="username" value="username" click="this.value=''"     class="user-name"> 

<input type="password" id="password"
name="password" value="password" onclick="this.value=''" class="user-name">


  <div class="login">

   <input type="button" id="signin" class="sign-button" onclick="
    var username=document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password= document.getElementById('password').value;

       edarah_Authenticate  (username,password, function(jsonResponse) {

        var auth = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
        for (i=0;i<auth.length;i++){
        if ((msg[i]['id'])!==null)
           { 

         Redirect();

           }
             else { alert('Username or Password is incorrect');}

         }                               });">
            </div>
```

here is the `soap.js` file :

```
    function edarah_Authenticate(username, password, theCallBack)
  {
   method = "Authenticate";



   parameters = "<username xsi:type='xsd:string'>" + username + "</username>
    <password xsi:type='xsd:string'>" + password + "</password>";


      edarah_getDataFromWebService(method, parameters, theCallBack);
   }
```

and there is continue but I think this is enough.

Comment: You could make sure the JS file is being loaded, by using a debugger tool, like Firebug.

Comment: the problem is i have another file called ser.html and has many function from the soap.js and working well all . i donno

Comment: Do you have any link to your site we could check?

Comment: are you sure soap.js is in the same folder as soap.html?

Comment: yes in the same  directory , unfortunately i cant give alink to the project . it is secret ^_^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i GUESS YOUR CODE IS TRUE .

JUST YOU HAVE TO CHECK THAT BOTH FOLDER IN THE SAME DIRECTORY ,i THINK THIS FUNCTION IS A WEB SERVICE YOU HAVE TO ACT IT AS A CLIENT .

Answer (score 0):

Look at your browser's error console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

You can't have a new line in the middle of a string literal in JavaScript. This is breaking your function declaration.

This would also have been picked up by [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) and [JSLint](http://jslint.com/) (as would some other issues, such as your use of globals for things that don't look like they should be globals).

Comment: THANX BOTH , BUT THE ERROR WAS THAT THERE ARE NOT IN THE SAME DIRECTORY , i ASKED THIS QUESTION BEFORE MAYBE MONTHS, HEHE , BUT THANX . i HAD FIX IT